# No line-after-line output from @Test block when running JUnit test with maven

Tags: maven, junit, maven-2, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a Junit test running under maven with 
mvn clean test -Dtest=MyTest

The output looks as following:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building autotest-tests
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] Deleting directory workspace/tests/target
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: compile tests}]
[INFO] Compiling 76 source files to workspace/tests/target/test-classes
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: run tests}]
[INFO] Surefire report directory: workspace/tests/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Concurrency config is parallel='classes', perCoreThreadCount=true, threadCount=2, useUnlimitedThreads=false
Output of @Before block...
Output of @Before block...
Output of @Before block...
```

Then the output stops. Any line by line output to command line from the @Test block is held back I see them on the console only after the test is over:

```
Output of @Test block...
Output of @Test block...
Output of @Test block...

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 75.564 sec
Results :
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 minute 18 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Feb 06 12:22:22 CET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/302M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I did work before, i.e. I was getting a line by line test output on the console as the test was proceeding. Since some time (maybe an update) stopped.

Any ideas what is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

The surefire plugin write the output to a file by default. This can be controlled with the [`useFile` option](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#useFile), which can be set from the command line:

```
-Dsurefire.useFile=false
```

It is also possible to set this as a default value in your `settings.xml` by creating and activating a profile:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sureFire.useFile</id>
        <properties>
            <surefire.useFile>false</surefire.useFile>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profile>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>sureFire.useFile</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Comment: I already set `<useFile>false</useFile>` in maven-surefire-plugin configuration in pom.xml. I guess it's the same thing.